# Any twitter api or complete solutions for monodroid?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

Looking for good solution for Twitter login and posting something... but there is no idea for now. How to do it in xamarine( IOS mono has complete solution, but monodroid...) help me please, if somebody knows how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to post something then you can easily do this by sending an Intent for use by an external app - e.g. see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/Share/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Share.Droid/MvxShareTask.cs#L19

If you need a more complete solution then libraries like Tweetsharp have had MonoDroid ports/branches at various times, but I don't know the current status of any of these.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to take a look [at Xamarin.Social](http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.social/). This component will let you tweet from your Xamarin.Android application.